# Place element in LinearLayout with minimal space between them

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a vertical `LinearLayout` with two `TextView`, the default space between them is to much big for me, I try to minimize it to almost 0 without success.

```
 <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/main"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:orientation="vertical"
          >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/text1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center"/>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/text2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center"/>

     </LinearLayout>
```

I tried to set `android:padding,android:layout_margin` on the `LinearLayout` but it doesnt work. I also tried to give to each `TextEdit` padding but it didnt halped aslo.

How can I place them near to each other?

Comment: TextView.setIncludeFontPadding(false) then add Iike 1dp padding?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try setting a custom background on the TextViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a negative `layout_marginTop` value to your text2 can minimize the space between the text showing, your layout goes like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/main"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:orientation="vertical"
          >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/text1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center"/>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/text2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
             android:gravity="center"/>

     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use android:layout_marginTop="-xxdp" for second textView
or layout_marginBottom="-xxdp" for first textView

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/main"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical"
      >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/text1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"/>

     <TextView
         android:layout_marginTop="-xxdp"
         android:id="@+id/text2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```